How to improve the fluidity of this code and track objects in real time with my mouse?
I'm creating a bot and the current system works, but since it's a simple code, I rely on the time between each print and photo processing. I'd like to make it continuous and move my mouse as the object is identified.
My problem is the delay between each loop execution. I would like to make it more continuous somehow, try to achieve real-time detection of the window instead of taking screenshots or something like that, to track as accurately as possible.
import threading
import time  
import pyautogui
import keyboard
from PIL import Image
from ultralytics import YOLO
import pydirectinput

# Function to move mouse to the center of the box and perform actions
def move_mouse_and_perform_actions(box):
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = box
    center_x = int((x1 + x2) / 2)
    center_y = int((y1 + y2) / 2)
    pydirectinput.moveTo(center_x, center_y)
    pydirectinput.press('f5')   
    
# Function to take screenshots
def take_screenshot(stop_event, model):
    screenx_center = 1920 / 2
    screeny_center = 1080 / 2
    pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False

    while not stop_event.is_set():
        # Take screenshot
        screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
        screenshot = Image.frombytes('RGB', screenshot.size, screenshot.tobytes())
        results = model([screenshot], conf=0.55)  # return a list of Results objects
        boxes = results[0].boxes.xyxy.tolist()
        classes = results[0].boxes.cls.tolist()
        names = results[0].names
        confidences = results[0].boxes.conf.tolist()
        
        # Process results list
        if len(boxes) == 0:
            pydirectinput.press('f4')  
        else:
            for box, cls, conf in zip(boxes, classes, confidences):
                x1, y1, x2, y2 = box          
                name = names[int(cls)]

                move_mouse_and_perform_actions(box) 

# Main function
def main():
    print('started!!!!')
    model = YOLO('best.pt')
    stop_event = threading.Event()

    # Create and start the screenshot thread
    screenshot_thread = threading.Thread(target=take_screenshot, args=(stop_event, model))
    screenshot_thread.start()

    # Listen for keyboard input to quit the program
    keyboard.wait("q")

    # Set the stop event to end the screenshot thread
    stop_event.set()

    # Wait for the screenshot thread to finish
    screenshot_thread.join()
    print("Program ended.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

